# Python: How to have a user input a string to test if equal to var

Tags: python, variables, input

So I am new to python and I know the very basics. I am making a sort of database, but you need a password to get in. I have a variable that is equal to the password, but I can't figure out how to have the user input something, then it tests if it is equal to the variable. I have a basic if statement, but I can't get the input. Here is my code currently:

```
print("Welcome to the NCPDFR Information Database. \nPlease print Password")
pw = "US1151944MC"
if pw = "US1151944MC":
print("Please enter name of search recipient")
else:
print("Password Invalid")
```

Comment: Take a look at `input()` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Also, you should probably change your password now.

Comment: Are you sure you know the very basics? Indentation is really important in python and `if pw = "...."` is trying to assign a variable inside a conditional which is invalid as well.  Pretty much any tutorial will cover all you need to know about this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get user input (and mask it) you can do:

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
```

For inputs that you don't want/need to mask in python, you can do:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter some text: ")
```

Note: `raw_input` is very much preferred over `input`

Comment: Unless the OP is using Python 3 - in which case `input` is the only option here...